# Xcode 11-beta3 build fails when project contains an asset catalog: error: unknown argument '--development-region'

Tags: xcode11

Trying to migrate an existing project to which contains an asset catalog to Xcode11/iOS13. Project builds and runs fine under Xcode 10.3, however when I attempt to compile it under Xcode 11-beta3, it fails with the following message:

> **: error: Unknown argument '--development-region'
>
>    Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code**

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a simple single-view application in Xcode 10.3
2. Add an asset catalog
3. Add an image set
4. Populate the image set
5. Build and run (project builds and runs fine in Xcode 10.3
6. Close Xcode 10.3
7. Reboot Mac (just in case)
8. Open Xcode 11-beta3
9. Open the above project
10. Build (build fails as described above)

Here is a zip file containing the project:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq5tGS9qpM0RrV3zn6_-vAdiDP5u

The project build successfully in Xcode 10.3 but not in Xcode 11-beta3.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing and re-installing xCode 11

Comment: I had one of those CompileAssetCatalog failures in the latest Xcode as well, 11.0 (11A420a). Worse than that, opening a storyboard crashed Xcode. The only thing that worked was deleting Xcode and installing it again (same version). Perhaps updating from 10.3 messes things up?

Comment: Were there any specific support folders you deleted during the uninstall? I tried removing Xcode and reinstalling, plus deleting the derived data folder, but the problem still persists for me on Xcode 11.4.

Comment: I just dragged the xcode app (bundle) to the trashcan and re-installed it.